# Running multiple django sites with mod_wsgi + apache causes memory issues

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm currently running 50+ Django installations with mod wsgi and noticing that apache isn't dropping memory (so it just keeps holding more and more, and then the sites grind to a halt as the swap disk fills). I also host some PHP sites on these servers.

Current wsgi config looks like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/glenlivet/tar/src/core/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess tar.sljol.info python-path=/var/www/vhosts/glenlivet/tar/src:/var/www/vhosts/.virtualenvs/glenlivet/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<Location />
WSGIProcessGroup tar.sljol.info
</Location>
```

I'm no expert, on this type of configuration, can anyone advise how best to setup each of the vhosts?

Thanks

Comment: Ensure you aren't using Apache 2.2 and old mod_wsgi version for a start. Apache 2.2 has issues with memory growth which is fixed in Apache 2.4. More recent mod_wsgi versions than the ancient versions Linux distributions provide also have workarounds to combat the Apache 2.2 issues, as well as other improvements to reduce memory used by Apache.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I'm running:

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38

and

Source: mod-wsgi
Version: 3.4-4ubuntu2.1.14.04.2

Comment: If you deal with large file uploads or downloads with slow HTTP clients, you will still see a measure of excess memory usage due to still using mod_wsgi 3.4.

Comment: Not particularly large, no. I've managed to stop the sites from keeping hold of too much memory. I think I'm going to look at clustering the sites together with a Django tech. If I want to have multiple Vhosts but have them use the same process pool is that possible?

Comment: If you are talking about using Django sites framework that can help in some cases. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: That's the intention, if I use seperate Vhosts for each of the sites, can I make them share resources by using the same name in the WSGIDaemonProcess and the same WSGIProcessGroup?

Comment: With my limited understand of the Django sites framework, I believe so as the whole intent is to allow multiple sites to run out of one Python interpreter. Just make sure you also set WSGIApplicationGroup to %{GLOBAL} else mod_wsgi will still try and separate them into different sub interpreters within the one process still.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a `maximum-requests` option that could be added to the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive which could help clean up the memory apache is holding onto for your Django applications.

Here is a quick snippet of documentation about this `maximum-requests` option...

> A further option which should be considered is that which dictates the maximum number of requests that a daemon process should be allowed to accept before the daemon process is shutdown and restarted. This should be used where there are problems with increasing memory use due to problems with the application itself or a third party extension module.
>   [Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines)

You will incur the overhead of apache having to reload your Django applications but may be more beneficial than swapping due to apache not releasing memory.

You may have to do some benchmarking to get a feel of what the maximum number of requests should be for your troubling applications but a good starting point could be the code below...

```
WSGIDaemonProcess tar.sljol.info python-path=/var/www/vhosts/glenlivet/tar/src:/var/www/vhosts/.virtualenvs/glenlivet/lib/python2.7/site-packages maximum-requests=10000
```